# Get list of all files and directories with their permission and owners

Tags: files, file-metadata

I need to generate a list of all files and directories with their permission and owner e.g.

```
-rw-rw-r--    black www-data     foo/
-rw-r--r--    black www-data     foo/foo.txt
-rw-rw-r--    black www-data     bar/
-rwxrwxr-x    black www-data     bar/foo.sh
```

I need this list to compare it with another instance where I have a bug.

Comment: Just for sure. You do not use selinux in the another instance.

Comment: if both directories are on the same system, you can use `diff`'s `-r` option to do a recursive comparison of files in both directories - e.g. `diff -u -r /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2`.   This will show files/subdirs that only exist in one of the two directories, as well as the differences between files with the same name, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU `find`, you can use its `printf` action:

```
find . -printf "%M %u %g %p\n"
```

This will list all files in the current directory and any subdirectories, with their type and permissions in `ls` style, owner and group, and full name starting from the current directory.

If you want consistent spacing, you can use field width specifiers, *e.g.*

```
find . -printf "%M %-20u %-20g %p\n"
```

You can output tabs with `\t`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be independent of the sometimes dynamically changing output format of `ls`, I would recommend using `stat` with the `--printf` option to have control over the outputs format. The following would create such a list in a more "machine-readable" format, using the `|` symbol as separator (the choice is arbitrary, see last paragraph for more on this):

```
stat --printf="%A|%U|%G|%n\n" /path/to/dir/* > list_of_tiles.psv
```

This would output the list of files and properties in the form

```
-rw-rw-r--|black|www-data|foo.txt
drw-rw-r--|black|www-data|bar/
```

However, this would by default not list the files and directories inside the sub-directories. To achieve that, there are several ways:

- If you are using bash, you can enable the `globstar` option to allow recursively-acting wildcard patterns:

  ```
  shopt -s globstar
  stat --printf="%A|%U|%G|%n\n" /path/to/dir/** > list_of_tiles.psv
  ```

  with output

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x|mygroup|myuser|subdir1
  -rw-r--r--|mygroup|myuser|subdir1/subfile1.txt
  -rw-r--r--|mygroup|myuser|subdir1/subfile2.txt
  drwxr-xr-x|mygroup|myuser|subdir2
  -rw-r--r--|mygroup|myuser|subdir2/subfile3.txt
  -rw-r--r--|mygroup|myuser|that_file.txt
  -rw-r--r--|mygroup|myuser|this_file.txt
  ```
- Otherwise, you may need to resort to GNU `find`:

  ```
  find . -printf '%M|%g|%u|%p\n'
  ```

  with output

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x|mygroup|myuser|.
  drwxr-xr-x|mygroup|myuser|./subdir1
  -rw-r--r--|mygroup|myuser|./subdir1/subfile1.txt
  -rw-r--r--|mygroup|myuser|./subdir1/subfile2.txt
  drwxr-xr-x|mygroup|myuser|./subdir2
  -rw-r--r--|mygroup|myuser|./subdir2/subfile3.txt
  -rw-r--r--|mygroup|myuser|./that_file.txt
  -rw-r--r--|mygroup|myuser|./this_file.txt
  ```
- If neither is available, this is a combination of both:

  ```
  find . -exec stat --printf="%A|%U|%G|%n\n" {} \;
  ```

Also note that this approach will only really be successful for your purpose of (automated?) comparisons if the filenames themselves don't contain the separator character `|` or new-lines (which are unfortunately also allowed characters). This is one of the reasons why it is discouraged to [parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/377345) [or `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/377345) via scripts. The same holds true for any choice of the separator character; this answer uses `|` simply because it is less frequently found in filenames than, e.g., the space.

Answer (score 1):

To get that information for a single file or directory on Linux, you may use the `stat` utility with a custom output format:

```bash
$ stat -c '%A %U %G %n' ~/.bashrc
-rw-r--r-- myself myself /home/myself/.bashrc
```

Would you want tab-delimited output, use `$'%A\t%U\t%G\t%n'` as the argument to the `-c` option (in shells that understand `$'...'` as a C-string).

To get the information for everything in the current directory and below, recursively, use `find`:

```bash
find . -exec stat -c $'%A\t%U\t%G\t%n' {} +
```

On BSD systems (any of the free ones, and macOS), you will want to use `stat -f '%Sp %Su %Sg %N'` instead (each `S` indicates "symbolic" output rather than numeric).  There, you may also use `%t` to insert tabs:

```bash
find . -exec stat -f '%Sp%t%Su%t%Sg%t%N' {} +
```

Example run on macOS:

```bash
$ tree
.
├── dir1
│   └── file
└── dir2
    └── othername

3 directories, 2 files
```

```bash
$ find . -exec stat -f '%Sp%t%Su%t%Sg%t%N' {} +
drwxr-xr-x  myself  staff   .
drwxr-xr-x  myself  staff   ./dir2
-rw-r--r--  myself  staff   ./dir2/othername
drwxr-xr-x  myself  staff   ./dir1
-rw-r--r--  myself  staff   ./dir1/file
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to redirect the results to a log file. Try using this:

```
ls -la /route/of/dir >> /route/ofyouneed/the/log/log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The `zsh` shell has both array comparison operators and a `stat` builtin to retrieve file metadata (since 1996 so predates both GNU and BSD `stat` which are from the early 2000s).

There you can do:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
details=()
for f ($dir/**/*(DN)) stat -LsH s -- $f && details+="$s[mode] $s[uid] $s[gid] $f:t"
```

Once you have those results for two separate directories in two arrays (like `$details1` and `$details2`, you can do:

```
print -rC1 'Only in first:' ${details1:|details2}
print -rC1 'Only in second:' ${details2:|details1}
print -rC1 'In both:' ${details1:*details2}
```